# Translate "If I would not exist if I will travel back in time, then I will not travel back in time" into predicate logic.

Tags: logic

"If I would not exist if I will travel back in time, then I will not travel back in time"

Translating the conditionals using ⊃ and 'I do not exist' as 'I am not something', find a tautologous form for this sentence, and draw a tree to check it is tautologous.

The completed tree has
a) one closed branch
b) two closed branches
c) three closed branches
d) four closed branches

I have no idea how to even translate this into quantifiers for me to check if it's a tautology, I tried translating it using propositional logic and the form wasn't tautologous. It's an exam question so the teacher won't reveal how to solve or what is the answer, but I would really like to know.

Comment: If the problem speaks of "predicate logic", presumably a "propositional translation" will not suffice; this is why you don not find a propositional tautology expression of it.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: details must be checked with your set or rules.

The argument is a sort of [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), provided that we add the implicit premise: "I exist":

> I exists; therefore: if (if I will travel back in time, then I would not exist), then I will not travel back in time

The exercise suggest to symbolize "I exist" as "I am something". Thus, I need an individual *constant* $I$ to name myself, writing: $\exists x \ (x=I)$.

1) $\exists x \ (x=I)$ --- premise

2) $\lnot [(Travel(I) \to \lnot \exists x \ (x=I)) \to \lnot Travel(I)]$ --- negation of the conclusion

3) $a=I$ --- from 1): rule for $\exists$: $a$ new

4) $(Travel(I) \to \lnot \exists x \ (x=I))$ --- from 2): rule for $\to$

5) $\lnot \lnot Travel(I)$ from 2): rule for $\to$

6) $Travel(I)$ --- from 5) by *Double Negation*

$7_L)$ $\lnot Travel(I)$ --- from 4): left branch by rule for $\to$

$7_R)$ $\lnot \exists x \ (x=I)$ --- from 4): right branch by rule for $\to$

The left branch closes by 6) and $7_L)$ and we are left with the right branch.

8) $\lnot \ (a=I)$ --- from $7_R)$: rule for $\forall$: $a$ old

The right branch closes by 3) and 8).

The tree closes, and thus we have proved:

> $\exists x \ (x=I) \vdash [(Travel(I) \to \lnot \exists x \ (x=I)) \to \lnot Travel(I)]$.

Comment: Don't you want to use something like "$E$" for the existence predicate, instead of using the existential quantifier? So that it more closely models our natural language interpretation of "exists".